# the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side

Tags: matlab

I am coding in matlab, and I wanted to compute this line :

```
bdiff(k+1, 1) = MatchCostNCC(blockL(:), blockR(:));
```

But I had the error saying that the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side. Knowing that blockL and blockR are 25by25. bdiff is just a variable where I stock the result on every iteration
here's my MatchCostNCC

```
function cost=MatchCostNCC(img1, img2)
%normalized cross-correlation
[nrow2, ncol2, ndim2]=size(img2);
win_size=9;
% params.ncc_winsize;


f=fspecial('average', win_size);
mu1=conv2(img1, f, 'same');
mu2=conv2(img2, f, 'same');

rau1=conv2(img1.^2, f, 'same');
rau2=conv2(img2.^2, f, 'same');

sigma1=rau1-mu1.^2;
sigma2=rau2-mu2.^2;

diff1=(img1-mu1)./(eps+sqrt(sigma1));
diff2=(img2-mu2)./(eps+sqrt(sigma2));

max_disp=14;
%params.max_disp;
% switch params.direction =-1
%     case -1
        disp_range=max_disp+1;
        pad_direct='pre';
%     case 0
%         disp_range=2*max_disp+1;
%         pad_direct='both';
%     case 1
%         disp_range=max_disp+1;
%         pad_direct='post';
% end   

cost=zeros(nrow2, ncol2, disp_range);
diff2_pad=padarray(diff2, [0 max_disp], 0, pad_direct);

for d=1:disp_range
      temp=diff1.*diff2_pad(:, d:d+ncol2-1,:);
      cost(:,:,d)=-conv2(temp, f, 'same');
end
```

Comment: without having `MatchCostNCC` how can we tell anything?

Comment: You can check it now.

Comment: bdiff seems to me like a variable of dimension 2, which will make bdiff(k+1, 1) a scaler. And cost is a variable of dimension 3. These two don't mix up well in matlab. You probably want to check out ["cell array"](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/cell.html?lang=en) (i.e. bdiff{k+1, 1}) or increase the dimension on the left (i.e. bdiff(k+1, :, :, :) to match the right.

Comment: the addition of the function isn't very helpful because there is no context. The function outputs a 3d array, is this what you want to save into a single "container" `bdiff(k+1, 1)` ?

Comment: Oh yes I need a singal value per iteration at bdiff(k+1, 1)